# Load balancing between 2 servers using MySQL Router

Tags: mysql, master-slave-replication, load-balancing

I want to setup a simple master-slave MySQL replication. I also want to balance the load between the 2 servers. Can I use MySQL Router 2.1 for that purpose? As I read the official documentation, it seems that MySQL Router now only works with InnoDB cluster. I don't have a need for InnoDB cluster. I just want to load balance 2 servers. Is the Router a good way to go, or should I look elsewhere?

Comment: Keep in mind that all writes are handled on both servers.  Do you have a lot of reads?  And you need to move some of the reads to the Master?

Comment: You can use **proxysql** for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can have a router for basic Master-Slave Replication. But use the routing strategy as "first-available".

Though this works, you should be aware that your slave will be in read-write mode (if you allowed it to be) and all write operations performed on slave should be manually synced with master.